# How to resume reading document opened in google pdf viewer

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

When I open a pdf in google chrome, I get the choice of opening it in google pdf reader, because I installed that app.

Now I want to resume the app to continue reading.

How do I list running apps to resume it?

It seems like I can click the downloaded file (in the notification area) to resume reading it where I was, but the notification area is something I clear regularily so that will not be an option.

Is there a way to get the download directory as an icon on the desktop?

Comment: You can try using a file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.poph), locate the download directory on your internal SD, select the folder by tick mark and from the 3button *more* options, choose *add to desktop*. Done

Comment: @Firelord I love that solution!

Comment: Convert it as an answer. Dragging the downloads app to the desktop is all I seem to need to satisfy my requirement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Google Chrome first have the file downloaded through Downloads app and then have it opened in the app chosen by user. Well in this case, you can just drag the Downloads app icon from your launcher's app drawer onto your home screen. Tap the icon and behold all your downloaded files available to you.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

You can also try beeshyams' [approach](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143484/how-to-resume-reading-document-opened-in-google-pdf-viewer#comment185068_143484) of using a third party file manager app, such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or [Amaze File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager). In both the apps, you can long press on the Download directory and under option choose *Add Shortcut* or *Add to desktop*. The folder would now be found on a new home screen as an icon.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]